# Query Won't Work in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to hide this button if the query result is = to btn1.CommandArgument.

The query works, because I have tested it, but the whole solution is not work.

If I replace

```
myCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString()
```

in the `if` statement to the query result, the button is hidden.

I have looked several times, but can't find any problems. Thank you.

```
protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    Button btn1 = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("addFollowerButton");

    // request Query string
    var querystring = Request.QueryString["ProjectId"];

    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    string select = "Select ProfileId from Project_Follower Where ProjectId = @ProjectId";

    using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        myConnection.Open();

        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(select, myConnection);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectId", querystring);

        myCommand.ExecuteScalar();

        if (myCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString() == btn1.CommandArgument.ToString())
        {
            Button hdn = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("addFollowerButton");
            btn1.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Problems like this become obvious if you write out both sides of the `if` statement to a log or to the browser response.  See also http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute the `.ExecuteScalar()` call only **once**! Grab the result (of type `object`) and then check to make sure it's not `null` and if it is, call `.ToString()` on it and compare to the other string you want to check against:

```
using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    myConnection.Open();

    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(select, myConnection);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectId", querystring);

    object result = myCommand.ExecuteScalar();

    if (result != null && result.ToString().Equals(btn1.CommandArgument.ToString()))
    {
        Button hdn = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("addFollowerButton");
        btn1.Visible = false;
    }
}
```